# how to convert time series "POSIXct" into Date format in R

Tags: lubridate, zoo

I have monthly time-series data in excel file. Its is "POSIXct" "POSIXt" class. I want to convert this data into date format = "%Y/%m". I want to increase one month in such a way that starting value is from Feb 95

```
    Date max    min     mean     PPT             Q
Jan-95  280.7   275.2   276.3   54.97001368 77.22654839
Feb-95  285.5   284.7   290.55  85.56014243 65.10167857
Mar-95  291.3   296.3   307.95  21.73403927 62.66664516
Apr-95  295.4    305    321     46.40860902 80.3805
May-95  302.3   314.6   335.4   101.350745  123.6887742
Jun-95  306.6   321.3   345.45  51.36630928 491.1493667
Jul-95  309.9   327.5   354.75  29.5892797  905.7528065
Aug-95  309.5   327.2   354.3   56.71881787 726.2029355
Sep-95  305.5   318     340.5   55.58525046 321.7907333
Oct-95  298     305.3   321.45  24.09003613 171.9048065
Nov-95  293.1   292     301.5   31.49880152 114.4126667
Dec-95  282.9   280.5   284.25  59.8837784  88.75790323

dataset <- read_excel("Gilgit.xlsx")
colnames(pr1)<-c("Date", "Q", "SEAS_1d")
pr1$Date<-pr1$Date+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I have monthly data when I open my data in R. It came in the following format.

```
pr1 <- read_excel("Gilgit.xlsx", sheet = 1)
colnames(pr1)<-c("Date", "Q", "SEAS_1d")
pr1$Date<-pr1$Date+1 
db1<-merge(db, pr1, by=c("Date"))
```

After adding date it looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AudjW.png)